# If I assign a value to a variable inside a method, does it persist beyond the scope of that method?

Tags: java

Sorry if this is a repeat, i've tried looking for the answer to my question but could not come across the answer I'm after.

I'm very new at Java (literally started yesterday) and I am trying to understand why if I declare a variable in my class and then assign a value to it in a **void** method, the value associated with that variable persists beyond the method's scope. My (very) limited understanding of methods is that they have their own scope and I thought the only way to access any variable changes that had been made within a method was to return them at the end of the method. Is this not the case?

Comment: the local variable (inside the method) doesn't exist (anymore) after execution of the method, but that doesn't go for the class/instance variable.

Comment: Kindly use reference books and bit practice will help

Comment: @Mr.Arjun I thought thats what StackExchange was for? To get helpful and kind answers on a question. Not to get referred to more technical reading?

Comment: @vcromy It's not being rude or kind to anybody. But it's just saving someone's productive time on something trivial. Kindly have a look at StackExchange's help section. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each method in a class will inherit any attribute (variable) or any method that directly belongs to that class. Say

```
public class Bicycle {

    public int gear;
    public int speed;

    // the Bicycle class has
    // two  methods

    public void setGear(int newValue) {
        gear = newValue;
    }

    public void speedUp(int increment) {
        speed += increment;
    }
}
```

Let's get the setGear method

```
public void setGear(int newValue) {
    gear = newValue;
}
```

As you can see, I can access the 'gear' attribute because it belongs to the Bicycle class. The parameter '(int newValue)' belongs to this method exclusively, meaning I can only access this variable inside this method, like this:

```
public void setGear(int newValue) {
    newValue = gear;
    //this wouldn't make much sense logic wise, but it is
    //valid code since I can use newValue only inside the setGear method

    speedUp(10);
    //the method 'speedUp' belongs to the bicycle class, so I can use
    //it inside another method belonging to the same class
}
```

Alternatively, I can use the `this` keyword to say that I am referring class attributes, like this:

```
public void setGear(int gear) {
    this.gear = gear;
    //I am telling the method that the class attribute 'gear' will 
    //receive my parameter value 'gear'
    //this is useful when my parameter variable name has the same 
    //name as my class attribute
}
```

Edit: forgot to give credit to the oficial oracle docs https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/classes.html

Comment: All answers here we're great but the depth and simplicity of this one did it for me. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 0):

The answer to this is a bit more complex.

First start to distinguish a *method* from a *function*.

A method operates on an *object* instantiated by calling the constructor of the class (e.g. `MyClass obj = new MyClass();`). From this point, your *object* has a *state* expressed by it's *member variables* (all variables that are **not** declared `static` in your class).
Methods (as part of the object) may change this state (unless the corresponding variables are declared `final`).

To be able to to so, a method inherits the scope of the class, but the variables are bound to the instance of the object, on which the method is called.

So for instance:

```
public class MyClass {
    private int a = 0;
    public void aplusplus() {a++;}
}

MyClass obj1 = new MyClass();
MyClass obj2 = new MyClass();
obj1.aplusplus();  // the a of obj1 is now 1
obj2.aplusplus();  // the a of obj2 is now 1
obj1.aplusplus();  // the a of obj1 is now 2
```

But beware! There is also a concept called *hiding*.
If you declare a local variable within the body of a method, it *hides* the class member variable. Accessing the variable by name results in accessing the local variable, instead of the member variable. This is particuallry interesting when implementing setter methods for private members, where usually the argument of the method (which is a local variable) is named exactly as the member variable. To still access the member variable, you can use `this.variablename`. For instance:

```
public class MyClass {
    private int a = 0;
    public void aplusplus() {a++;}
    public void setA(int a) {this.a = a;}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You say in your question that you have declared a variable in your **class**. This means that any value the variable gets set to, (during method invocations), will persist across method invocations. The variable is part of **this** object, and as such, is referred to as an **instance variable**.

If you declare variables inside method definitions, they are inside the scope of the method. They are part of **this.yourMethod()**. These variables are said to be local to the method. You can only use these variables inside the method. The **this** object does not know they exist.